# Andengine Tiledmap How to make sprites impassable by another?

Tags: andengine, collision, sprite

I have a working collision system to sprites that i dont want "player" to pass. Problem is that i have no idea what should i execute on collision to make player not pass sprites.

wallCollision() method is currently empty.

```
if(tmxTileProperties.containsTMXProperty("collision", "1")) {       
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(tmxTile.getTileX(), tmxTile.getTileY() ,128, 128, mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) 
    {
        @Override
        protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed)
        {
            if (player.collidesWith(this))
            {
                wallCollision();
            }
        }
    };
    rect.setVisible(false);
    mainScene.attachChild(rect);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question located [here](http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/collision-objects-from-tmx-map-t3907.html) addresses this.  The method below creates a JBox2D body at the same position as the blocked tile.  I'm not sure how this works in conjunction with the pathfinding to exclude blocked tiles, but I've seen the same approach used in other places, assuming you're using GLES2.  Hope this helps.

```
  private void createUnwalkableObjects(TMXTiledMap map){
                // Loop through the object groups
                 for(final TMXObjectGroup group: this.mTMXTiledMap.getTMXObjectGroups()) {
                         if(group.getTMXObjectGroupProperties().containsTMXProperty("wall", "true")){
                                 // This is our "wall" layer. Create the boxes from it
                                 for(final TMXObject object : group.getTMXObjects()) {
                                        final Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(object.getX(), object.getY(),object.getWidth(), object.getHeight());
                                        final FixtureDef boxFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0, 1f);
                                        PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, rect, BodyType.StaticBody, boxFixtureDef);
                                        rect.setVisible(false);
                                        mScene.attachChild(rect);
                                 }
                         }
                 }
        }
```